# Came home to find garage door control panel inverted

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, garage

I'm sure there isn't a setting that does this. I'm even more sure someone broke into my garage, stole nothing, and just decided to set the screen to invert.

It still works fine. The buttons work, I can open the door; everything seems to be okay, except that the screen is now inverted.

[image: Crazy]

Comment: @isherwood  I prematurely VTC because there was no question asked and no model number. VTRO

Comment: @Mark Probably because if the users took the tour, they'd know to ask a clear and concise question. If they don't, then they'll not know to up vote or "check"  a good answer. Then we have to deal with it later as an unanswered question. We all "police" this site.

Comment: @JACK I am voting to leave open. The brand is visible and the problem is obvious  Closing the question is frightening for new users as the wording is terse. Abd it wont teach them about up voting.

Comment: @RohitGupta  I voted to reopen three hours ago.

Comment: Whoever programmed this was happy with displaying "DOOR WILL CLOSE IN 1 MINUTES". How does this give you confidence that this isn't just a software error?

Comment: @TonyK - It probably is a software error (especially given the answer below that suggests rebooting), but how does that help?

Comment: @TonyK - It should have been "Door will close in %d minute(s)".   (assuming a C type language).

Comment: @SteveWellens: that is the half-way solution, yes

Comment: If constrained, I always code a number display as, eg. `Mins to Close: 1`, which reads naturally without a conditional branch.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like a common issue.
Solution is to turn it of and on by cutting power.

Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfH_HQ2iPSc

Comment: Regarding how this can happen: even if the door control panel doesn't expose this setting to the user, many LCD controller chips have a configuration bit to flip the display (called display scan direction). Some random power spike can have flipped that bit, and after a reboot the main processor will restore the correct configuration.